# Jquery: please help explain this code because I need to tweak it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain this to me? I'm trying to understand exactly why drop down lists inside a li tag work okay but when using a form the menu disappears when clicked anywhere.

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

It works in combo with:

```
$("html").click(function() {
  menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Full code with menu example:

http://jsfiddle.net/e4yy4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code

```
$("html").click(function() {
  menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

would remove the `active` class of the menu and so hide it when ever a click is detected anywhere on the page.

But

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();});
```

Would override the first piece of code when the click is detected in the drop down list.

So you can add the below code to override the first piece of code so it also cancel the hiding when clicking in the form.

```
menu.find('ul > form').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();});
```

Just like this
http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/e4yy4/3/

Answer (score 0):

You also want to stop `form` events propagating to `html` (should probably be `document`).

Change the selector to select descendent `form` elements too.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/rQ7sx/).

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, could you elaborate on what you mean by probably should be document? And what would be different by combining the form and a like you did versus splitting them up like Quincy did above? Thanks

Comment: @trying_hal9000: I usually let events propagate to `document`, not the `html` element, though it probably doesn't matter in your example. Splitting them up would make no difference, just make the code more verbose and violating DRY.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the first check to `menu.find('ul li>*')` then it seem to work.
I think that line was only handling clicks on links, and your form elements aren't links.

Answer (score 0):

`<form>` is an element just like any other, as such, it should be eligible for selection using the CSS selectors (which are called by the `find()` function).

You need to change your selector to include the `<form>` tag and possibly change the selector to pickup on `<input>` elements instead of `<a>`.

For more information on jQuery selectors, please see: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/